# Is it thread safe to read properties of Javafx controls?

Tags: javafx, thread-safety

I know it's unsafe to write to Javafx control properties outside of Javafx thread.
But is it also unsafe to read?

This is what I want to do:

```
void runNoneFXThreadCode() {
  // Calculate some slow math operation
  ...

  // Now get the current value of Javafx textfield
  String result = textfield.getText()
  
  // Calculate another slow math operation based on result
  ...
}
```

What's the best way to achieve above in thread safe manner?

I've been doing it without `runLater` and never had issues in Windows. But I wonder if it might be problematic in Mac or Linux.

If this reading is not thread-safe please leave the link to specification that explicitly mentions reading is unsafe. Most I could find only talk about writing being unsafe.

Comment: It’s difficult for me to see the context here. Typically (best practice) if you start a background thread you’d retrieve the data from the UI on the FX application thread, create an immutable object representing it, and pass that object to your background process. The code you posted doesn’t make much sense to me, as in the second version `result` is scoped to the lambda expression, so wouldn’t be available to another thread. Please clarify with a [mre].

Comment: Generally, as far as I know, it is not safe to read these properties on another thread. I just don’t really understand why you’d want to.

Comment: Once the immutable object is created in FX application thread, how do you return the result to the other? I updated my question to include a more complete example.

Comment: Use a `Task` that invokes `updateValue`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavafx%5d%20task%20updateValue).

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Thread-Safety

Fundamentally, the only thing that matters when it comes to thread-safety in Java is whether or not the necessary *happens-before* relationships have been created. Some of the rules can be quite subtle (such as those surrounding `volatile`). To learn more about this, check out:

- The [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) package documentation.
- [§17.4.5 Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) of the *Java Language Specification*.

### JavaFX

JavaFX is [explicitly not thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546).

> The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface of a JavaFX application, is not thread-safe and can only be **accessed** *[emphasis added]* and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application thread.

In general, the objects of the JavaFX libraries are not implemented to handle concurrent threads operating on them simultaneously. This is true regardless of which threads are involved. More narrowly, once an object is connected to the "live" UI, where "live" essentially means "part of a window that is showing", then those objects must only be accessed and modified on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. This restriction is mentioned many times throughout the various documentation. And some objects, such as `Window` and `WebView`, have even stricter restrictions where they must *never* be touched by a thread other than the FX thread, regardless of if they're "live".

Note *some* operations in JavaFX will first check that they were invoked on the *JavaFX Application Thread*, throwing an `IllegalStateException` if not. But many operations will *not* perform this check.

---

## Addressing Your Question

You asked:

> What's the best way to achieve above in thread safe manner?

If you only need to read that one `TextField` in the middle of your background task, then a quick and somewhat dirty solution is to use `CompletableFuture`. Replace:

```
String result = textField.getText();
```

With:

```
String result =
    CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(textField::getText, Platform::runLater)
        .join();
```

But it also seems like what you have is two separate tasks, where the second depends on the result of the first. In that case, use two implementations of `Task` and start the second one when the first one succeeds. This approach is [demonstrated in the answer by @James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73417485/6395627). Also see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546).

---

## Is Reading UI State on a Background Thread Safe?

The answer is basically, "no, but also it kind of depends".

### Short Answer

No, reading UI state on a background thread is not safe. Just act like that's always true and I would be surprised if you can go wrong. Whereas trying to reason if one particular scenario is thread-safe can easily lead to mistakes or break in the future.

### Long Answer

In the simplest case, reading UI state on a background thread is unlikely to cause any undesirable side-effects. For example, the following application:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
  
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var label = new Label("Hello, World!");
    
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Thread-Safety");
    primaryStage.show();

    var thread = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(label.getText()));
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
  }
}
```

Should be thread-safe, if I'm not mistaken. The label's text property is set **before** starting the background thread. That is to say, setting the text property *happens-before* starting the background thread. Therefore, the background thread should always read the latest value (i.e., not read a stale value).

Now, one might think this sort of thing is always safe because you're only reading state, not writing state. But you can't always be sure that calling a method will definitely not cause any writes. For instance, the text property of the label inherits from `StringPropertyBase` (implementation detail). And that class maintains a "valid" state. When you call `getText()` you end up causing `valid = true` to be executed. Alert! That's a write! Is that likely to cause problems? Probably not in this specific case. But the point is you *don't always know* what side-effects something as innocuous as reading some state will cause (unless the documentation explains otherwise).

Even if there are no writes, you might still end up reading a stale value. Say your user is trying to delete a directory and they choose the wrong one. They fix it before starting the delete action, but somehow your task reads the old, *incorrect* directory and deletes that one instead. Given the nature of UI interaction, my intuition says this scenario is unlikely if not impossible, but imagine your user's horror at irrecoverably deleting their family photos instead of some old documents. And their anger when they realize this was caused by a *bug in your application*. Better to just code your application so this cannot possibly happen unless by user error.

**In conclusion, you should assume reading UI state from a background thread is unsafe.** This is good practice in general Java programming, too. Assume an object is *not* thread-safe unless explicitly documented otherwise; always ensure that a *happens-before* relationship is created when communicating between threads.

Besides, it's not any harder to write the following 100% thread-safe code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
  
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var label = new Label("Hello, World!");
    
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Thread-Safety");
    primaryStage.show();

    // Read UI state on FX thread, pass values to background task
    var text = label.getText();
    var thread = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(text));
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: I had read the spec but somehow didn't notice the phrase "accessed" in there, thanks for emphasizing it. Your explanation of why read can be unsafe too is what I was looking for. Thanks for detail explanation. I like your proposed solution which is much shorter than Tasks. I suspect most can be done your way, although some may require a Task. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @SaeidNourian One thing I'd be cautious about is that you seem to be potentially saving intermediate state in the UI. If you are, then you should not be doing that. The UI can certainly display progress information to the user, but the task(s) should manage their own state. That is to say, the intermediate state should be handled by the model.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment my biggest problem is finding all the places were I made Javafx calls from outside of Javafx thread. Is there an easy way to find all of them quickly?

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to only find UI calls that occur on a background thread (I'd be surprised if any such static analysis tool could do this reliably).

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, you basically have two operations that need to be run in the background. Create separate tasks for each operation. So this would look something like:

```
private Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

void runNoneFXCode() {
    Task<SomeType> firstTask = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        protected SomeType call() {
            return doFirstOperation();
        }
    };
    firstTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        String text = textField.getText();
        SomeType computationResult = firstTask.getValue();
        Task<SomeOtherType> secondTask = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected SomeOtherType call() {
                return doSecondOperation(text, computationResult);
            }
        };
        secondTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            SomeOtherType completeResult = secondTask.getValue();
            // update UI with completeResult
        });
        exec.execute(secondTask);
    });
    exec.execute(firstTask);
}

private SomeType doFirstOperation() {
    // long computation...
    return result ;
}

private SomeOtherType doSecondOperation(String text, SomeType result) {
    // long computation...
    return result ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of Task but was hoping a read action didn't need it. Your solution looks good, but I have hundreds of such access currently in my code, oh well, guess I better start coding.

Comment: @SaeidNourian You might want to rethink your strategy. Do you really need to get the most recent value? If so, other solutions may be possible: you could create your own thread-safe object to encapsulate all the data you need, and update it from change listeners, for example.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment my biggest problem is finding all the places were I made Javafx calls from outside of Javafx thread. Is there an easy way to find all of them quickly?